# Getting datatype of all columns in a dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame in which following data is loaded:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTjEC.png)

I am trying to develop a code which will read data from any source, load the data into data frame and return the following o/p:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y2Kk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `schema` property and then iterate over the fields.

Example:

```
Seq(("A", 1))
  .toDF("Field1", "Field2")
  .schema
  .fields
  .foreach(field => println(s"${field.name}, ${field.dataType}"))
```

Results:

[image]

Make sure to take a look at the [Spark ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).

Answer (score 0):

Thats the closest I could get to the output.
Create schema from case class and and there after created DF from the list of schema columns and mapped them to a Dataframe

```
import java.sql.Date

object GetColumnDf {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    val map = Map("Emp_ID" -> "Dimension","Cust_Name" -> "Dimension","Cust_Age" -> "Measure",
      "Salary" -> "Measure","DoJ" -> "Dimension")

    import spark.implicits._
    val lsit = Seq(Bean123("C-1001","Jack",25,3000,new Date(2000000))).toDF().schema.fields
      .map( col => (col.name,col.dataType.toString,map.get(col.name))).toList.toDF("Headers","Data_Type","Type")
    lsit.show()
  }

}

case class Bean123(Emp_ID: String,Cust_Name: String,Cust_Age: Int, Salary : Int,DoJ: Date)
```